# Scala CRUD pojo generation

Tags: scala, code-generation, pojo

I am trying to think of a way to implement a simple CRUD API in Scala with POST and PATCH methods for a type `Foo`. So, I have definitions for for my API of actual type `Foo`, a `POST` pojo and a `PATCH` pojo as follows:

```
case class Foo(
  id: String,
  field1: String,
  field2: Int
)

case class CreateFoo(
  field1: String,
  field2: Int
)

case class UpdateFoo(
  field1: Option[String],
  field2: Option[Int],
)
```

I'd like to avoid all this boiler plate and keeping all 3 classes in sync, ie if I wanted to add `field3: Boolean`. I started reading up on type macros and it seems to be the right tool for the job to generate all my pojos. However, I feel like this problem must be already solved and Im reinventing the wheel. Is there an already made solution?

Comment: Case classes are not POJO

Comment: Macros are good for generating bodies of functions or inserting new functions into existing classes (via macro annotations). They aren't codegens which could create new top-level classes. I guess you could take a look at http://yefremov.net/blog/scala-code-generation/ or similar posts or at scalameta. I can also think of type-level solution ("higher-kinded types") but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok's comment is basically the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need code generation, so why don’t use a code generator (like Telosys for example https://www.telosys.org/ )

With such a tool you define your class only once (in an “entity” file) and it generates all the repetitive code (wathever the language, in your case Scala)

Comment: I will certainly take a look, but by now I already ended up copy/pasting all the boiler plate. Might still come in handy for next time, though.